# "scoring must return a number" cross_val_score error in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

Maybe it is a dumb question, but I don't understand the error that the function `cross_val_score` in the code below give me. Perhaps the answer is in the format of `X` sample, seeing that this is exactly what was shown in the crash message, but I don't know how to fix.  This is a piece of code from my project with some random values.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import mixture,cross_validation

np.random.seed(0)
n_samples = 300
C = np.array([[0., -0.7], [3.5, .7]])
X = np.r_[np.dot(np.random.randn(n_samples, 2), C),
          np.random.randn(n_samples, 2) + np.array([20, 20])]

clf = mixture.GMM(n_components=2, covariance_type='full')
score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X)
```

Gives me the error:

```
ValueError: scoring must return a number, got (<type 'numpy.ndarray'>) instead
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this may be an issue in scikit. `cross_val_score` ultimately makes a call to the `score` function for whatever estimator is passed to it. Typically, `score` (e.g. in `KMeans`) [returns a float](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html#sklearn.cluster.KMeans.score). And when a `KMeans` estimator is passed to `cross_val_score`, all is well:

```
>>> clf = cluster.KMeans()
>>> score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X)
# (no error)
```

Note the return type of `score`:

```
>>> clf = cluster.KMeans()
>>> clf.fit(X)
>>> type(clf.score(X))
numpy.float64
```

When `score` is called on a `GMM` an [array is returned](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html#sklearn.mixture.GMM.score).

```
>>> clf = mixture.GMM()
>>> clf.fit(X)
>>> type(clf.score(X))
numpy.ndarray
```

Because `cross_val_score` is relying on `clf.score()` returning a float, the error message you see would make sense.

A workaround is to supply `cross_val_score` with your own scorer. For example, to take the average of the scores returned by `GMM.score()`, create this scoring function:

```
>>> scorer = lambda est, data: np.mean(est.score(data))
```

Then you can pass this scorer as an argument to `cross_val_score`:

```
>>> score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(clf, X, scoring=scorer)
```

This avoids the error, and I think should more or less do what you're looking for. I'm not sure if the mean is necessarily the best way to summarize the scores, though it seems reasonable enough. But from here you can define your own method.